# How to check if domain in blocked by Proxy Server -- Using JQuery/Client Side scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

*Scenario*

I have a video file which is stored on Youtube and on my server. I have two pages in php

*page1.php*
simple page showing a link with following: page2.php?videoid=1

*page2.php*
If the client has youtube access then I will stream the video from youtube else will stream from my server.

Here is what I think I should do:

1. After page1.php is generated. I will test using cleint side java script if Youtube is accessible from that client.
2. Somehow pass the result obtained in step 1 to page 2.

Question:

1. Is this the correct/viable approach
2. Any java script network library that will solve Step 1
3. How do I pass this value obtained in step 1 to page2

Answer (score 0):

You could send an ajax request to the youtube url and check the response code. if it's 200, you're good, anything else, use your own server.

You could add a click handler to the link on page 1 to do this. Use the result of the ajax request to determine which way to view the video and pass that as a query string parameter to page 2.